# MySQL Query using $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, maybe I'm a bit overtired, but I can't understand why this isn't working! I have a comments box on my website, with profiles for people who post. I want to show just their posts in the profile. Their profile page is userinfo.php?user=(whatever)

This query is failing:

```
$query = "SELECT message,`date`,ip,name,website,id 
          FROM `guestbook_message`
          WHERE name=" . intval($_GET['user']) . "
          AND deleted=0
          ORDER BY `date` DESC";
```

Comment: How is it failing?  Can you post the query on multiple lines?

Comment: This query is fine, there's something else bugging you.

Comment: Have you tried to run your final query into phpMyAdmin or whatever system that you use to administrate your DB?

Comment: Ok but what error gives you? in query syntax or just doesn't return any record?

Comment: $name = intval($_GET['user']);
  $query = "SELECT message,`date`,ip,name,website,id,hits FROM `guestbook_message` WHERE name='".$name."' AND deleted=0 ORDER BY `date` DESC";
  $total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));  

This shows no results.

Comment: Ok, so as @shamittomar pointed out, if you look for a usernmane and not an ID number, using INTVAL() will castype the string to an integer, of course you're not retrieveing results..Refer to his answer donw here to get the likely solution

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the name of the user and casting it directly to integer and then comparing it with name. This does not make sense.

If the `$_GET['user']` is the ID of the user, then compare it with the `ID` and not with the `name`.

If $_GET['user'] is the username of the user, then you have to put the quotes around the username value. As UserName value is a string, you need to encapsulate it in quotes and remove the `intval`. Do it like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT message,`date`,ip,name,website,id
           FROM `guestbook_message`
           WHERE name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']) . "'
               AND deleted=0
           ORDER BY `date` DESC";
```

Comment: I think you mean "If the `$_GET['user']`..." :)

Comment: $_GET['user'] is the username of the account.

Comment: @tom If its the **username** of the account, `intval()` is not correct. use `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user'])` instead. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$name = intval($_GET['user']);

$query = "SELECT message,date,ip,name,website,id 
          FROM guestbook_message 
          WHERE name='" .$name. "' 
          AND deleted=0 
          ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `mysql_query()` to execute the query, have you checked if the query succeeded?

```
$query = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Doing this will force the script to abort if the query fails and tell you why the query failed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note that using $_GET directly in your query leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Consider cleaning your input prior to building your SQL statement, or use PDO / Prepared statements.

Comment: 1) This should be a comment not an answer. 2) It's technically not being used DIRECTLY in the query since it's being passed into the `intval()` function which should convert it to an `int` or `die()` trying. That said however, `intval` is not a legitimate way of sanitizing that variable for use in a SQL query. So I definitely agree with you. :)

Comment: I'm not using the $_GET directly in the query.